# I'm having a problem with lists in my basic quiz software

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am running the code block written below:

```
class Question:
    
    def __init__(self,text,choices,answer):
        self.text = text
        self.choices = choices
        self.answer = answer
        
    def checkAnswer(self, answer):
        return self.answer == answer
 class Quiz:
    
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.questions = questions
        self.score = 0
        self.questionsIndex = 0
        
    def getQuestion(self):
        return self.questions[self.questionsIndex]
    
    def displayQuestion(self):
        question = self.getQuestion()
        print(f"Question: {self.questionsIndex +1}: {question.text}")   
        for q in question.choices:
            print("-"+ q)
        answer = input("Your Answer:  ")
        self.guess(answer)
        self.loadQuestion()
        
    def guess(self, answer):
        question = self.getQuestion()
        if question.checkAnswer(answer):
            self.score += 1
        self.questionsIndex += 1
        self.displayQuestion()
        
    def loadQuestion(self):
        if len(self.questions) == self.questionsIndex:
            self.showScore()
        else:
            self.displayProgress()
            self.displayQuestion()
            
    def showScore(self):
        print("Score: ", self.score)
        
    def displayProgress(self):
        totalQuestion = len(self.questions)
        questionNumber = self.questionsIndex + 1
        if questionNumber > totalQuestion:
            print("Quiz Finished")
        else:
            print(f"*************************Question {questionNumber} of {totalQuestion}***********************************")
           

q1 = Question("Which programming language is the most profitable?["C#","Python","Java","HTML"],"Python")
q2 = Question("Which is the easiest programming language?", ["C#","Python","Java","HTML"],"Python")
q3 = Question("What is the most popular programming language?", ["C#","Python","Java","HTML"],"Python")
questions = [q1,q2,q3]
quiz = Quiz(questions)
quiz.loadQuestion()
```

And I am facing the following problem:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Onur/Desktop/Artificial Intelligence A-Z/sorularclass.py', wdir='C:/Users/Onur/Desktop/Artificial Intelligence A-Z')
*************************Question 1 of 3***********************************
Question: 1: Which programming language is the most profitable?
-C#
-Python
-Java
-HTML
 Your Answer:  a
Question: 2: Which is the easiest programming language?
-C#
-Python
-Java
-HTML
Your Answer:  a
Question: 3: What is the most popular programming language?
-C#
-Python
-Java
-HTML
Your Answer:  a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 63, in <module>
    quiz.loadQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 44, in loadQuestion
    self.displayQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 29, in displayQuestion
    self.guess(answer)
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 37, in guess
    self.displayQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 29, in displayQuestion
    self.guess(answer)
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 37, in guess
    self.displayQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 29, in displayQuestion
    self.guess(answer)
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 37, in guess
    self.displayQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 24, in displayQuestion
    question = self.getQuestion()
File "C:\Users\Onur\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence A-Z\sorularclass.py", line 21, in getQuestion
    return self.questions[self.questionsIndex]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you tell me the reason for this? Why is there a problem with lists? I'm adding this because stackoverflow wants me to add more details: I tried to build a quiz using basic class methods in this software, but I ran into a problem.

Comment: For starters, `if len(self.questions) == self.questionsIndex:` is wrong; you want to compare to `self.questionsIndex - 1`, since if a list is of a particular size, its final index is one less than its length, since indices start at zero. I think that might solve your issue - there might be more, but at first glance that issue stood out to me.

Comment: You need to make an [mcve], for example, clearly your issue wont' require every single function here to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `displayQuestion` method you call the `guess` method. In the `guess` method you increase the `questionsIndex` value, and call `displayQuestion` method again.

This process repeats and repeats infinitely until the `questionIndex` goes `out of range`. It seems that you need to remove calling the `displayQuestion` method from the `guess` method.